# Android - Pinning location to map when clicking a listview item?

Tags: android, listview, android-mapview, android-alertdialog

I have a listview that contains a couple of taxi companies. When a user clicks on the taxi name, it shows an alertdialog box asking them to either book, show map or cancel. What im trying to achieve is when the user clicks show map, it grabs the location from a string array already set, and then points to it on the map. I dont want it to find my current location as of yet. is this possible to do? i already have a mapview setup which at present just points to a random location set from the tutorial.

This is my code for both:

```
    ListTaxi Class : 

             class Taxi {
    private String taxiName;
    private String taxiAddress;
    private String taxiDist;

    public String getName() {
        return taxiName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        taxiName = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return taxiAddress;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        taxiAddress = address;
    }
    public String getDist() {
        return taxiDist;
    }
    public void setDist(String dist){
        taxiDist = dist;
    }
    public Taxi(String name, String address, String dist) {
        taxiName = name;
        taxiAddress = address;
        taxiDist = dist;
    }
}

public class TaxiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Taxi> {
    private ArrayList<Taxi> items;
    private TaxiViewHolder taxiHolder;

    private class TaxiViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView address; 
        TextView dist;
    }

    public TaxiAdapter(Context context, int tvResId, ArrayList<Taxi> items) {
        super(context, tvResId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.taxi_list_item, null);
            taxiHolder = new TaxiViewHolder();
            taxiHolder.name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_name);
            taxiHolder.address = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_address);
            taxiHolder.dist = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_dist);
            v.setTag(taxiHolder);
        } else taxiHolder = (TaxiViewHolder)v.getTag(); 

        Taxi taxi = items.get(pos);

        if (taxi != null) {
            taxiHolder.name.setText(taxi.getName());
            taxiHolder.address.setText(taxi.getAddress());
            taxiHolder.dist.setText(taxi.getDist());
        }

        return v;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listtaxi);

    final String[] taxiNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_name_array);
    final String[] taxiAddresses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_address_array);
    final String[] taxiDist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_array_dist);
    ArrayList<Taxi> taxiList = new ArrayList<Taxi>();

    for (int i = 0; i < taxiNames.length; i++) {
        taxiList.add(new Taxi(taxiNames[i], taxiAddresses[i], taxiDist[i]));

    }


    setListAdapter(new TaxiAdapter(this, R.layout.taxi_list_item, taxiList));  

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id)
        {       

            final int selectedPosition = position;
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListTaxi.this); 
             adb.setTitle("Taxi Booking");
             adb.setMessage("You Have Selected: "+taxiNames[selectedPosition]); 
             adb.setPositiveButton("Book", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(ListTaxi.this, Booking.class);
                     intent.putExtra("booking",  taxiNames[selectedPosition]);
                     intent.putExtra("address",  taxiAddresses[selectedPosition]);
                     intent.putExtra("distance", taxiDist[selectedPosition]);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             });
             adb.setNeutralButton("Show Map", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(ListTaxi.this, Map.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             });

             adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); 
             adb.show();
         }
     });     
}
```

}

and my map class is :
                /**
 * 
 */
package com.taxime;

```
    public class Map extends MapActivity{
LinearLayout linearLayout;
MapView mapView;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
ItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapviews);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        itemizedOverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(drawable);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                if (intent.getData() != null) {
                    int selectedPosition = Integer.parseInt(intent.getData().getHost());
                    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(selectedPosition, selectedPosition);

                    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

                    //...
                }
            }
        }
```

Also my strings come from :

```
    <string-array name="taxi_name_array">
    <item>Barrys Taxi</item>
    <item>Boom Taxi</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="taxi_address_array">
<item>24 test address, Uxbridge, UB8 2JY</item>
<item>14 test 2 address, Uxbridge, UB91JD</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name = "taxi_array_dist">
<item>0.4 miles</item>
<item>0.8 miles</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name ="location">
<item>(19240000,-99120000)</item>
</string-array>
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be awesome.

Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the data field of the intent to pass the position of the taxi item that was clicked to the map activity. To do this, inside the `onClick` handler for the "Map" button, you use the `Intent` constructor that takes four arguments:

```
adb.setNeutralButton("Show Map", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("taxi:" + selectedPosition), ListTaxi.this, Map.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Then, inside the map activity, you call the [`getIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) method to retrieve the `Intent` that started it. Calling [`getData`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29) on the intent retrieves the data field.

Putting it all together, you will have something like the following in the `onCreate` override of the map activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (intent.getData() != null) {
            int selectedPosition = Integer.parseInt(intent.getData().getHost());
            String[] taxiLocations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.location);
            String location = taxiLocations[selectedPosition];
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and this will allow me to pull in the coordinates from the string array set and then when clicked pin it to the map?

Comment: @Oli: Yes, as long as you keep the association between position and taxi company data the same (so in this respect, I highly recommend creating a `ContentProvider` so that you do not have to hard-code taxi company information). If you manage to keep the association consistent (i.e. 0 is always Yellow Cab Co., 1 is always Orange Cab Co., 2 is always Checkered Cab Co., etc.), then you will know that the coordinates from the string array at `selectedPosition` are the ones corresponding to the taxi cab company that was clicked.

Comment: ah ok cool. at the moment it will always be in that position. i will eventually change it so that the list arranges itself on closest taxi first. Ill give this a shot and let you know how i get on. cheers dude

Comment: Hi mate ive tried pulling it across but i cant work out how to call it across in the mapview using that code? any suggestions?

Comment: @Oli: I don't understand what you wrote. Can you rephrase your question? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: i cant seem to get it to work basically lol. it just force closes when i try showing map. i cant work out how to pull in the coordinates on the map.java and get them to show on the map.

Comment: @Oli: Why don't you post the complete source of `Map.java`, which I presume is the map activity, correct? Also, where do you define the string array containing the coordinates of the taxi companies?

Comment: @Oli: In the same way that you accessed the taxi company names and addresses in your main activity, you can call `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.location)` within your map activity. I have updated my answer to do this. Note that you have data for two taxi companies, but there is only one string value in the array of locations. You're missing one. This is what I was referring to by needing to keep the association between position and taxi cab company information consistent, and that it's trickier without using a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: hey thanks for that! the problem i have though is actually plotting it onto the map. ie i need to convert that string into a geopoint dont i?

Comment: @Oli: Oh, yes. To do that, you will need to parse a string like "(19240000,-99120000)" into the constituent numbers. One solution is something like: http://pastebin.com/4LXiM6pP

Comment: @Oli: Also note that the `GeoPoint` constructor takes the latitude and longitude multiplied by 10^6. For example, the lat/lon of Big Ben is 51.500611,-0.124611, so you pass the pair of integers 51500611, -124611 to the `GeoPoint` constructor.

Comment: ah cool :). do i need to set anything in my listacivity? as its forcing close again? i think the map activity bit is correct though.

Comment: @Oli: Force closing problems are caused by one of two things: An uncaught/unhandled exception or doing too much in the UI thread. There is too much to discuss on these issues in this little space, so I recommend reading as much as you can on the Internet about it. Good luck!

Comment: managed to get it working. needed to declare strings in listtaxi first. amazing stuff. thanks for that piece of code dude

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have an address and need the lat/lon to set the map to? Something like this perhaps:

```
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext()) ;
    List<Address> addresses = null ;

    try {
       addresses = gc.getFromLocationName("123 Main St, Peoria IL 61601", 10) ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Address a = addresses.get(0) ;
    double lat = a.getLatitude() ;
    double lon = a.getLongitude() ;

    MapController mc = mapView.getController();

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lon * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(18);
    mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: no at the moment im just using coordinates. so basically i have a string array with a field set for coordinates. when a user clicks that listview item, it pops asking if they want to show it on map and then takes them there. if that makes sense?

Comment: In Daniel's answer you should have a String location - presumably in the format of "123456,123456" corresponding to a latitude/longitude. Then use part of Joe's answer to create a new GeoPoint, once you've parsed the string correctly.